# How to convert a horizontal table into vertical table - SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table on Snowflake

| category | Metric1 | Metric2 | Metric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Second | 4 | 5 | 6 |

And I want my table to be like:

| Metrics | First | Second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Metric1 | 1 | 4 |
| Metric2 | 2 | 5 |
| Metric3 | 3 | 6 |

I have a way of doing this with `UNPIVOT` function in Snowflake-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
    UNPIVOT
    (DATA for Metrics in 
    (
    Metric1, 
    Metric2, 
    Metric3
    )
    )
```

However, it somehow returns to

| CATEGORY | METRICS | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FIRST | Metric1 | 1 |
| FIRST | Metric2 | 2 |
| FIRST | Metric3 | 3 |
| SECOND | Metric1 | 4 |
| SECOND | Metric2 | 5 |
| SECOND | Metric3 | 6 |

which is not something I want.

Could anyone please help me with this in one SQL query **without** creating a new table?

I think there is a way to solve this issue with `UNPIVOT`, but I couldn't figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were spot on in your original SQL ... just needed to [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) the Category back:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM CTE UNPIVOT 
          ( DATA FOR METRICS IN (METRIC_1, METRIC_2, METRIC_3))
) 
PIVOT (SUM (DATA) FOR CATEGORY IN ('FIRST','SECOND') )
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT 'FIRST' CATEGORY, 1 METRIC_1 ,2 METRIC_2,3 METRIC_3
UNION
SELECT 'SECOND' CATEGORY, 4 METRIC_1 ,5 METRIC_2,6 METRIC_3)
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM CTE UNPIVOT ( DATA FOR METRICS IN (METRIC_1, METRIC_2, METRIC_3))
) 
    PIVOT (SUM (DATA) FOR CATEGORY IN ('FIRST','SECOND') )
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select v.metric,
       max(case when t.category = 'First' then v.value end) as first,
       max(case when t.category = 'Second' then v.value end) as second
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('Metric1', metric1),
             ('Metric2', metric2),
             ('Metric3', metric3)
     ) v(metric, value)
group by v.metric;
```